# How change text in div by javascript

Tags: javascript

Please, help me :)

I have this HTML:

`<div class="delivery-time">Delivery to: <strong>18.7.2018</strong></div>`

How to change in Javascript to have this HTML?:

`<div class="delivery-time">Ship to: <strong>18.7.2018</strong></div>`

It means, have the same date in `<strong>`, but change text in `<div>` (before `<strong>`)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Unfortunately no, only javascript :(

Comment: `document.querySelector('.delivery-time').innerHTML = 'Ship to: <strong>18.7.2018</strong>'`. If you want to be dynamic, then `document.querySelector('.delivery-time').innerHTML = `Ship to: <strong>${value}</strong>` ` for example.

Comment: But I must first read the date from strong ...

Comment: Write it using the template string then. " ` ` ". So, it will be `Ship to: <strong>${new Date()}</strong>` . `new Date()` is just an example.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have this HTML. I do not know the date, I must to find out this date from the HTML first ...

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to target the first [text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) in the element by using [firstChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild). You can change just its [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and leave the other nodes within the element intact:

```js
document.querySelector('.delivery-time').firstChild.textContent = 'Ship to: ';
```

```html
<div class="delivery-time">Delivery to: <strong>18.7.2018</strong></div>
```

Comment: Nice tip on just updating the textContent, I never thought of that and I think its a more elegant solution if all browsers handle that the way the should and not dump any children elements

Comment: :) the real magic is that it's not the element's textContent that is being updated, but the first textNode's. Most people are unaware that the space between elements are text nodes and can be targeted with JS (though not CSS).

Comment: Thx, amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can't use jQuery you can still use what it's backed by, document.querySelector. So with that in mind, find your element by the class and update the innerHTML property of the element. Here is a very basic example:

```
var element = document.querySelector('.delivery-time')
var time = element.querySelector('strong').innerHTML
element.innerHTML = 'Ship to: <strong>' + time + '</strong>'
```

Comment: But I must first somehow read the date from strong ... I need something as: "change text in .delivery time before <strong> :)

Comment: @Jirin I just saw that comment so i updated the solution for you

Comment: @Jirin I would love to take credit for a great solution but take a look at skyline3000 solution, it's better.